Cannot access a folder on Windows 11 partition from Ubuntu 22.04 after recent Windows update
On my HP laptop running Windows 11 & Ubuntu 22.04, due to low space on Ubuntu partition I had created a folder[backup] on Windows 11 partition that I could access after I boot Ubuntu 22.04. I used to add data to to the folder that I had named "backup" folder every now and then.
Recently I had to boot into Windows that automatically started updating before shutdown. When I booted into Ubuntu, the folder[backup] was not present, but the size of that Windows partition did not change. I ran sudo update-grub to see if it made any difference.
The folder[backup] can be seen now, but it shows empty, and the size of that windows partition is still the same. Apparently the data on the folder[backup] is present, but not accessible as can be seen in the images attached.
The properties of the partition shows 101.9 GB used:

The properties of the contents of the partition shows only 259 MB size:


Are you backing up to NTFS? Not recommended as NTFS does not support ownership & permissions, so you lose those. Windows updates often turns on fast startup again or maybe bitlocker. It may even update UEFI which then goes to defaults & needs those settings changed https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

This looks like a windows problem or something caused by windows so not one we can fix :P

@oldfred Yes i am using NTFS windows partition from Ubuntu to backup data...I am able to access the Windows partition from ubuntu, except for the backup folder shows ZERO bytes, but the partition has not freedup that space....little over 95GB

@Rinzwind I am able to access the Windows partition from ubuntu, ther is no problem mounting the partition..

@oldfred There is no problem with mounting the said windows partition, never was, even after this recent windows update....only the said backup folder from that partition looks empty as has been shown in the images i have shared

If Windows has hibernation or fast startup on, then anything from Linux is lost when it restores the hiberfile. Normally the Linux NTFS driver does not allow mount read/write when it sees hibernation. But it can be mounted read only. There now are two NTFS drivers NTFS3 & NTFS-3G. Not sure of differences.
